# Lucene Query nested OR

Tags: regex, solr, lucene

I'm having difficulty writing a query that will return all of these possible string values.
To make the situation more difficult there can be more than 1 set of |###>###| blocks in one string so using OR between these simply won't work.

I may be using grouping improperly with the OR operator, as every attempt I've used ends up requiring me to begin the match at "schema3".

This is how I pictured it in my head:

item_s:schema3|(a OR atext OR "")>(a OR atext OR "")|

```
item_s:schema3|a>|
item_s:schema3|>a|
item_s:schema3|atext>|
item_s:schema3|>atext|
item_s:schema3|atext>a|
item_s:schema3|a>atext|
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using a StandardAnalyzer for you queries and indexing, in which case you have a couple problems with the query you listed.

you are trying to create a phrase query, in effect here.  The colon is being interpreted by Lucene, which is why you can only attempt a search starting at "schema3".  the query:

```
item_s:somestuff
```

will search for "somestuff" in a field name `item_s`.  If you enclose the whole thing in quotes, that should remedy that for you.

Second, you can't enclose logic or wildcards in a phrase query, In order to match precisely the terms you indicated, you would have to enumerate all 6 (or 9) possibilities, like:

```
"item_s:schema3|a>|" "item_s:schema3|>a|" "item_s:schema3|a>atext|" etc.
```

(to clarify, the `OR`s aren't really required in Lucene syntax, it's the default operation, and I prefer `+/-` syntax to `and/or/not` for Lucene).

If you aren't so concerned about the precise correct ordering of terms, and are willing to rely on Lucene's scoring algorithm, then you can make life a bit easier, and query more like:

```
+"items_s:schema3" +(a atext)
```

Which requires a match on the prefix "items_s:schema3", and on either (or both) of "a" and "atext".

One note, if  it is critical that you maintain the same precise format, including punctuation, then you will need to index using a keyword or whitespace analyzer, that maintains punctuation (you may, of course, be doing that already).

Comment: Thanks femtoRgon, though I couldn't find a solution to this exact problem it does seem that what I was trying to do is not possible. The stored data represents a hierarchy tree, and it's stored as a string. From a bit of initial research it seems there's a better way to store this sort of information. I would vote up, but I don't have 15 rep yet :(

Comment: Ah, I see.  Looking into [Solr's faceted search](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrFacetingOverview), perhaps?